# Background offset from bottom with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fallback

I'm trying to write a script with *jquery* that substitutes the **CSS** *calc()* function for browser compatibility. What I'm trying to rewrite is `background-position: center calc(100% - 80px);`

My attempt was somewhat like this:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('#element').css('background-position', 'center 100%').css('background-position', '-=80px');
});
```

but then what do I substract from, the first or the second value? I needed help on that, couldn't think of any possible solution :/

**EDIT**

To make it more clear, I was trying to have my background image positioned 'center bottom' with 80px y-axis offset, '100%' in this case equals 'bottom'.

**ONE MORE EDIT**

So finally, I found out.

For this to work, we need to have an **img** element somewhere on the page with **display:none**, containing the background image in original width. Let's give it an ID **#referrer**. We could as well create it with jquery and set the **img**'s **src** to the **element**'s background image, but it's rather complicated, we'd need to get the background image url from the DOM's CSS, so we just create it manually.

like this:

```
<img src="our-img.png" style="display:none;" id="referrer" />
```

then we can call this function when needed (in my case on window resize)

```
function larg() {
    foo = $('#element').height() - $('#referrer').height();
    $('#element').css('background-position-y', foo + 'px');
};
```

That's how we make the image's bottom aligned with the element's bottom.
Now all we need to do to make an offset is add the numeric value of offset pixels to **foo**.

We can modify our function to take an argument, so we don't have to modify it everytime we change our offset.

```
function larg(bar) {
    foo = $('#element').height() - $('#referrer').height() + bar;
    $('#element').css('background-position-y', foo + 'px');
};
```

Then we can call it basically from anywhere, in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85yyz/), it's called by buttons **onClick** after resizing the div like this:

```
<button onClick="$('#element').css('height', '300px');larg(-80);">300/-80</button>
```

Note that it's not universal and works only if the background image is in original size.

**FINAL EDIT**

[Don't ask me why didn't I know it.](http://jsfiddle.net/85yyz/2/)

```
background-position: center bottom 80px;
```

But I wrote a rather cool piece of code, right?
This line of CSS doesn't work in IE8, therefore the code is useful, though minimally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to be sure about parameter, you can use [background-position-y](http://www.css3.com/css-background-position-y/) only (not far all browsers)

(you can even simply add 80px transperent margin directly to your picture and always use `background-position: center bottom;` in css)

**FINALLY** I made [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/rp5Bh/1/) with unusual solution

```
$('#slide').css('background-position', 'center bottom 80px')
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but doesn't it move the background up 80 pixels everytime you resize the window (if put into window resize function), resulting in the background sliding off the screen in the end? :D

Comment: I would think it would just produce an error, but that's just me ?

Comment: So you're trying to say that I can just use 100%-80px? That's... Well, unexpected.

Comment: nope. try taking the CSS rule out and setting height to 100%. what it does is that it takes the percentage without the percent sign and substracts 80, then adds the px suffix, resulting in 20px background-position-y.

Comment: Yes. But remove the CSS rule. The code doesn't work, it's just that the rule stays set.

Comment: oh, sh.., you're write, then check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/rp5Bh/1/) and my edition (I consciously made 10px in script to check it). Is that what you tried to do?

Comment: You. Are. A God.
No jquery.
No Calc.
I'm just doing easy things the difficult way.
Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rp5Bh/2/)

Comment: Maybe somebody will find the OP useful.

Comment: @user2359063, why did you take off acceptance then?